# In this problem how did they realise that the probability of tails is 1/3?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was looking at the solution for this problem but I don't understand where they come to the conclusion that the probability of tails is 1/3. I understand that they multiply this by 2 to get the probability of heads.

A coin is twice as likely to turn up tails as heads. If the coin is tossed independently, what is the probability that the third head occurs on the fifth trial?

Answer (score 1):

If you're twice as likely to get "heads" as "tails", and the probability of "tails" is $p$, then the probability of "heads" is $2p$.

Next, notice that these have to add up to $1$, so
$$
p + 2p = 1.
$$

Then solve that equation for $p$ and you get $p=\dfrac 1 3$.

Comment: Thank you! That was so simple! I don't know why I was getting so mixed up!